# Relation between volume element of metric g and its pillback

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-integration

Given a diffeomorphism $\Phi:(M,g)\longrightarrow (M,g).$ I want to know is there any relation between volume element $dV_{g}$ of  the metric $g$ and the volume element $dV_{\Phi^{*}g}$ of the pullback metric ${\Phi^{*}g}$  or not?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes, it should be $dV_{\Phi^*g} =\det(T\Phi)\cdot dV_g$

Comment: Sorry, what is T in the equality?

Comment: It wants to denote the tangent map (differentiation) of $\Phi$, $\ T\Phi:TM\to TM$.